# Server error when URL ends with ' /'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to capture the exception and route the request to 404 handler when my application url ends with ' /'. I have added exception handling in Application_Error method in global.asax, but this breakpoint never gets hit.

I also have custom errors set up in web.config file.

Note: I see the same error with msdn websites as well.

Example:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/' /'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/'%20/')
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/'; /'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/';%20/')

How can I handle these exceptions at application level and show a custom error page?

**Error message when custom Errors is turned off**

[image: Error message when custom Errors is turned off]

Comment: Same behavior [http://msdn.microsoft.com/ /](http://msdn.microsoft.com/%20/) without quotes.

Comment: Same thing on SO [https://stackoverflow.com/ /](https://stackoverflow.com/%20/) :) When you disable custom errors what does it look like?

Comment: Configuration Error  
  
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.  
  
Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have added the `customErrors` in your `Web.config` file correctly.

I have used following config and it is working fine.

```
<system.web>

    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/Error/InternalServerError" mode="On">
      <error redirect="/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="/Error/InternalServerError" statusCode="500" />
    </customErrors>

    ...
```

E.g. [http://coursenet.lk/ /](http://coursenet.lk/%20/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my application is ok. I am sorry I am unable to expose my production website url. However, you need to configure your application pool to be integrated and not classic. I am assuming you are using the latest IIS.

Also, you need to put the custom error in the `system.web.server`, for example:

```
<system.webServer>
...
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ErrorPage_404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>
...
</system.webServer>
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.